# errores en JSON

Tags: php

Cual es la mejor manera de gestionar los errores cuando no hay resultados para un consulta?
Ejecuto la consulta y hago el encode del JSON, si hay datos perfecto, pero si no hay resultados no lo gestiono bien.

```
if (isset($_POST['elemento'])) {
        $especie = $_POST["elemento"] ?: ''; 
    }
    $statement = $cnn->prepare("
    SELECT 
        -- datos --
    FROM 
        -- table --
    WHERE 
        -- condiciones --
        and id_font = 3
        ");
        
    $valor = $statement->execute();
    

    if( $valor ){
        while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $data["data"][] = $resultado;
        }
        echo json_encode( $data );
    }else{
        echo " error";
    }
```

Si arroja resultados que coincide que tienen id_font = 3, sin problema, si tienen otro valor da error del estilo `Notice: Undefined variable: data in funciones_PHP/distribucion.php on line 35 null` claro porque no hay resultados. Como podría gestionar mejor esto del error? probé con un array de respuesta, pero no acerté a hacerlo bien. Se podría generar un JSON vacío?

Comment: Podrías devolver un objeto similar a este: `{ resultado: 'OK', mensaje: 'Sin datos', datos: [] }`. De esta manera, aunque no devuelvas datos siempre vas a obtener del servidor algo que además te aporta información para actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: puedes agregar un  parámetro indicando la cantidad de resultados `{ cantidad: x }`, en el front realizar determinada acción cuando dicha cantidad sea 0

Comment: me sigue dando el Undefine variable data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo agregando a la respuesta una clave `error` cuando algún error ocurra y al recibir el JSON verificar si la respuesta contiene o no una clave `error` simplemente.

Considera que si se espera un JSON, debes responder SIEMPRE con un JSON, no puedes hacer `echo` de una cadena simple en esos casos como ahora estás haciendo.

De esta manera debería funcionar:

```
$mData=array();

if( $valor ){
    while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $mData[] = $resultado;
    }
    #Si el array sigue vacío es porque no había filas
    if (!$mData) {
        $mData['error']='No hay filas';
    }
}else{
    $mData['error']='Error de consulta SQL';
}
echo json_encode($mData);
```

Luego, donde recibas `$mData` verificas si tiene o no una clave `error` y actúas en consecuencia: mostrando el error o en su defecto, pasando a leer los datos.

Comment: Vale, me daba error pero parece que ahora me funciona, modifiqué un par de líneas pq no hacía el `json_encode($mData);` en concreto cambié la línea del resultado del While `$mData["data"][] = $resultado;` y para controlarlo un poco mejor después cuando el array sigue vacío lo puse como array vacío ` $mData["data"][]='';` y puedo hacer después en javascript que me muestre el div con el botón. Gracias @A. Cedano

Comment: @Esti19 se puede hacer de ambas formas. A mi me gusta más agregar una clave `error` porque de ese modo puedes informar al usuario final de una forma más específica cuando algún error ocurra. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.